# how to assert for boolean value in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a flag of type boolean "worklogMatch". I need to assert this flag for 'true'. If this is not true, I would need to print the ERROR value. Here is my code,

```
List<WebElement> worklogObj = driver().findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ng-scope']");
boolean worklogMatch = false;
ArrayList<String> worklogDescriptions = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<worklogObj.size(); i++) {
    worklogDescriptions.add(worklogObj.get(i).getText());
    log.info("Text of the worklogs: "+worklogObj.get(i).getText());
    if (worklogObj.get(i).getText().equals(worklogDescription)){
        worklogMatch = true;
        break;
    }
} 
assertTrue(worklogMatch == true, "worklog Description "+worklogDescription + " is not saved. List of "+ "worklog description found for the incident " +incidentNumber +" is" + worklogDescriptions);
```

When I assert this, the boolean variable worklogMatch is set as false as the String that I'm looking for is not present in the ArrayList. The test case fails as expected. However, the message is not dispalyed in the console. My questions,

1. Is my way of assertion valid? I'm asserting a boolean variable with 'true'
2. Why is my message not being printed when the assertion fails?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, way of assertion is correct, one thing that i've changed is not compare worklogMatch to true in assertion
2. According to the [doc](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29), message should be written as first arg

now assert will look like:

```
assertTrue("worklog Description "+worklogDescription + " is not saved. List of "+ "worklog description found for the incident " +incidentNumber +" is" + worklogDescriptions, worklogMatch);
```

Comment: I wanted to compare the value of 'worklogMatch' to 'true'. How can we do this in assertion?

Comment: You can do it by your old way, but this is redundant to compare 'worklogMatch' to 'true' in assertion because worklogMatch is boolean type. Anyway both assertion will work correctly `assertTrue(worklogMatch == true)` or `assertTrue(worklogMatch)`